# Android: How to center two full width buttons in the center?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSetDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="Set Date" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSetTime"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:text="Set Time" />
```

How to center two buttons like the image?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its  Simple! here we go...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSetDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Set Date" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSetTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Set Time" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap your buttons into a content such as LinearLyaout, use android:gravity="center_vertical" and it will work.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="btn1" >
</Button>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="btn2" >
</Button>

</LinearLayout>
```